# Powershell script to disable all Windows 10 Notifications?

Tags: windows, powershell, regedit

Is there a way to disable Action Center Notifications in Windows 10 with PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way with 2 registry keys,
`DisableNotificationCenter` and `ToastEnabled`.

```
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows" -Name "Explorer" -force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" -Name "DisableNotificationCenter" -PropertyType "DWord" -Value 1
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications" -Name "ToastEnabled" -PropertyType "DWord" -Value 0
```

This works with PowerShell 5 on Windows 10 EN, Version 21H2.